# Selenium webdriver get value from data-bind on span tag

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I need to get the value from this  tag

```
<span>
    <a class="jsk-sa-dialog link-lightbox-valores" data-bind="attr: { href: '#sa-valor-' + $root.types().id }" href="#sa-valor-2">
    Link to click that pop-ups a new window
    </a>
</span>
```

After look at the "html" code in debugger, I saw the text that I want to get into HTML... 
To get the text that is generated into the popup window, I wrote this code:

```
case "someBaseText":    
{
    details.Click(); // Simulate the click on <a> tag
    var tx = details.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='overview-material']"));
    var dv = tx.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='sa-valor']/h3"));
    var ttText = dv.Text; // Empty :(
}
```

The HTML that i got from debugger:

```
<div class="overview-material">
<div class="valores" data-bind="foreach: $root.types">
<div class="sa-valor" data-bind="attr: { id: 'sa-valor-' + id }" id="sa-valor-2">
<h3 class="titulo">Mensalidade</h3>
<div class="texto" data-bind="html: apresentacao.valor">
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

So, I want to get the text inside of div class "texto"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the XPath of `dv`, you are getting the `<h3>` element:

```
<h3 class="titulo">Mensalidade</h3>
```

therefore `dv.Text` should return `"Mensalidade"`.

---

Try updating your XPath to the `<div>` with `class='texto'`:

```
//div[@class='sa-valor']/div[@class='texto']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CssSelector:

```
var text = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.texto")).Text;
```